# What does this code in SQL do?

Tags: mysql, sql

What does this part of code do?

```
ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I've searched on the internet about the MyISAM and it's the default storage engine, and the CHARSET=utf8 is used for special characters.

Comment: "Used for special characters" is a gross oversimplification,  but you apparently already know what they are for.

Comment: Here's the documentation for the MySQL "create table" statement: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-table.html

Comment: Thank you AD7six and triber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ENGINE=MyISAM` Set DB Engine sample it And InnoDB ...
`AUTO_INCREMENT=1` Set Start number of `id` Or Primary KEY
`DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;` SET charset For Other Languages Or other char's 
This code is part of DB config And usually used in .sql files ...
This code is Query And Used in MySQL Database's

Comment: No Problem ;) search About Mysql And See W3schools.com

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it.

with `ENGINE=MyISAM` you specify that you are using `MyISAM` engine.

with  `AUTO_INCREMENT=1` you are resetting the `auto-increment`field to start from 1.

with `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` to specify default server character set and collation.

Answer (score 0):

Its a part of a [`CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) statement.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     data VARCHAR(100)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`ENGINE` defines the DB engine.
`AUTO_INCREMENT` initializes the start number of the primary key
`DEFAULT CHARSET` sets the character set for your fields.

Answer (score 0):

`ENGINE=MyISAM` means that the table created will be using the MyISAM engine. If possible us InnoDB

`AUTO_INCREMENT=1` means that the each record will be automatically assigned a number starting with number 1 for the first record

`DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` - this is driving the type of characters - read more here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8